# What does mtp://[usb:002,003]/Storage/ mean?

Tags: filesystems, mtp

Recently that I connect my Windows phone mobile to my Xubuntu laptop I see `mtp://[usb:002,003]/Storage/` alongside the other drives.It shows my phone media files! That actually I can not find it in terminal!

So can I access to its file system information at all? and also I want to know is there any way that I could access other data on my phone like documents or messages or ... ?

Comment: It will be in `/run/user/1001/gvfs/mtp:host=%5Busb%3A002%2C003%5D/`. For how to access it, let's hope someone answers the duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

MTP stands for Media Transfer Protocol, the stuff in brackets seems to be an address of a certain USB device in Xubuntu and /Storage is obviously a folder on that device. I'm not sure you could access it via terminal but you could check if FUSEfs would help you. Otherwise just find a software which work with data via MTP. I'm sure Xubuntu would have standard one.